# Is there a way to configure a base url on react-query's QueryClient?

Tags: reactjs, api, url, axios, react-query

Well, I have this very simple file where I export a QueryClient from react-query library:

/queryClient.ts

```
import { QueryClient } from "react-query";

export const queryClient = new QueryClient();
```

Is there a way to set up a base url, or should I use something like context provider in order to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Well, as shown in this article:

[React Query and TypeScript](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-and-type-script)

And on the docs:

[Default Query Function](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/default-query-function)

You can configure a default query function:

```
export const queryClient = new QueryClient({
    defaultOptions: {
        queries: {
            queryFn: async ({ queryKey: [url] }) => {
                if (typeof url === 'string') {
                    const { data } = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/${url.toLowerCase()}`)
                    return data
                }
                throw new Error('Invalid QueryKey')
            },
        },
    },
});
```

Being able to call the UseQuery instance passing only the params of your api method call:

```
// You can even leave out the queryFn and just go straight into options
 function Post({ postId }) {
   const { status, data, error, isFetching } = useQuery(`/posts/${postId}`, {
     enabled: !!postId,
   })
 
   // ...
 }
```

Comment: Side note: I didn't know leaving out params in JS functions was even a thing. For this I had a look into react queries code and found their `parseQueryArgs()` util function and the multiple type declarations for `useQuery()` in the .d.ts file. I am in a mixture of mindblow and amazement right now.

Comment: Glad to here that. Up vote if it helped you somehow. :)